# How to follow many users at once on Twitter

Tags: javascript, twitter

I want to follow many users at once on twitter accounts with only one click due to reaching my limit? I tried this code but it doesn't follow any all:

```
$('.button-text.follow-text').trigger('click’);
```

I have been doing this via the javascript console, but it doesn't work

I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: Just a heads up, this probably wont work, as using code is only going to simulate if you were to click the button yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> On twitter.com the follow button has `.follow-btn` class

**Try with(pure javascript):**

> This example don't require another libraries like jQuery, angular, etc...

```
// Get all elements
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.follow-btn');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    // Trigger click on element
    elements[i].click();
}
```

And, you example have a syntax error. Try replace `’` for `'`.

**Example(as jQuery):**

> This example require jQuery

```
$('.button-text.follow-text').trigger('click');
```